# Awesome Grid buttons hiding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, razor, grid

I'm using **Awesome Grid** from `aspnetawesome.com`.
I'd like to hide the default `refresh` and `pagination` button but from the documentation I can't find nothing about this.

Any ideas to solve this ?

Comment: check it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

.ShowFooter(false)

Comment: Glad to help you. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved with: **.ShowFooter(false)** method